# Раскладка языка в PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Всем привет!

Странный вопрос может показаться, но тем не менее напишу. Не могу переключить языковую раскладку в IDE PhpStorm. На клавиатуре переключение, в панели винды тоже идет смена языка. В других приложениях текст переключается в соответствии с языком. Тут же не переключается. Почитал статейки про:

http://webmaster-gambit.ru/php-storm-smena-raskladki-ne-rabotaet-pereklyuchenie-yazyika/

https://akuma.su/blog/kak-ubrat-glyuk-s-raskladkoy-v-phpstorm.html

И ничего не помогает, честно говоря. С такими ошибками в первые сталкиваюсь. Это что-то из области того, что может случиться, раз в 100 лет у программиста). Специально только так можно сделать, глюк такой сам по себе маловероятен...

Что не так делаю?

Comment: снести и переставить не?

Comment: Моё решение помогло? Просто интересно.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле это глюк самой IDE, но насколько знаю баг так и не исправили.
Я решил проблему путем изменение клавиш на переключение раскладки (**именно CTRL + 1...2..3**, с SHIFT не работает).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]